Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.ts
I am creating a react component that creates a custom html element and sets innerhtml using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, everything goes fine but the issue arises when I provide the dynamic type to the ref it give typescript error

Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.ts(2590)

/**
 * This component is responsible for adding the innerHtml in the html element using dangerouslySetInnerHTML with html sanitization.
 */
import React, { HTMLAttributes } from 'react';
import { isObjectEmpty, isStrEmpty, sanitizeHtml } from './helpers';
import withErrorBoundary from './withErrorBoundary';

// All valid HTML tags like 'div' | 'form' | 'a' | ...
type ValidTags = keyof React.JSX.IntrinsicElements;

// Generic type to generate HTML props based on its tag
export type DangerousHTMLProps<T extends ValidTags> = {
    tag?: T | ValidTags;
    htmlString: string;
    sanitizeProps?: object;
} & (HTMLAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>);

const defaultTag = 'div';
function DangerousHTMLComponent<T extends ValidTags = typeof defaultTag>({
    tag = defaultTag,
    htmlString,
    sanitizeProps = undefined,
    ...rest
}: DangerousHTMLProps<T>, ref: object): React.ReactElement {
    // Stateless variables
    const ParentElem: keyof React.JSX.IntrinsicElements = tag;
    const sanitizePropsObj: object = isObjectEmpty(sanitizeProps) ? sanitizeProps as object : {};

    if (isStrEmpty(htmlString)) {
        return <ParentElem {...rest} />;
    }

    return (
        <ParentElem
            {...rest}
            ref={ref}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitizeHtml(htmlString, { ...sanitizePropsObj }) }}
        />
    );
}

const DangerousHTML = React.forwardRef(DangerousHTMLComponent);
export default React.memo(DangerousHTML);


I tried providing the generic type but it always throw error.
I don't want to disable this typescript rule as there are various answer in the internet regarding disabling this rule for this error.

You need to provide more details: 1) what editor are you using? 2) Why do you need to pass the ref here in the first place?

I am creating a component that can dynamically create a html element and add sanitized  innerhtml.
